# Gamma ray bursts and global cooling

Tags: supernova, gamma-ray-bursts, climate

I watched the latest video of [kurzgesagt channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/Kurzgesagt?app=desktop), which is regarding [supernova/gamma ray bursts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q4DF3j4saCE), and its effects on earth. In the video he explains how gamma ray bursts or supernovas affect our earth. He said that gamma rays can trigger global cooling/ ice age and on researching further I found that late [ordovician-silurian extinction](https://www.aps.org/publications/apsnews/200407/extinction.cfm) may be caused by a gamma ray burst.

In the video he said about that gamma rays can cause production of free ions which can provide *breeding grounds* for massive clouds to form, obstructing the sun and cause global cooling. However I couldn't understand why this happens or what its mechanism is? I tried to find one research paper concerning [biogeochemical effects of GRB](https://arxiv.org/ftp/astro-ph/papers/0503/0503625.pdf), but it revolved around cocnentration of $NO_x$ gases, so I couldn't find any satisfactory answers. So my question is exactly how a GRB can cause global cooling on earth?

Comment: https://astrobiology.nasa.gov/news/how-deadly-would-a-nearby-gamma-ray-burst-be/ is a place to start.

Comment: kurzgesagt Is really great on this, they post their sources right in the description! https://sites.google.com/view/sources-supernovadeath?pli=1